# questions related to wrk2 benchmark tool about their latencies and requests

Tags: lua, benchmarking, load-testing, latency, wrk

I have some questions in my mind related to wrk2 benchmark tool. I did a lot of search on them and did not find answers related to them. If you have little understanding related to them then please help me.

1. What "count" column represents in Detailed Percentile spectrum? [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO65j.png) Did they show the total number of requests whose latency is within "value" (column name) range? Correct me if i am wrong.
2. What "latency(i)" and "requests" represent in done function provided by wr2 and wrk? and How can I get that values? [done_function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXHZT.png)
3. How can I get the total number of requests generated per minute and their latencies? Does "latency(i)" and "requests" give me some information about them?
4. What "-B (batch latency)" option in wrk does? My output remains the same whether i use this option or not. [batch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ9iN.png)
5. In wrk2 readme.md, i didn't understand these [lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RKAi.png). can you please explain that.